# How to get all elements from Revit files uploaded in the system using Revit API

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

we can view the Revit file on Autodesk forge viewer.

And we need to get all elements from Revit files uploaded in system using Revit API.

we are trying using below link
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/

But unfortunately we are getting below error
"Token does not have the privilege for this request."
errorcode : AUTH-010

Please help me how to resolve the error

Our main aim is to get all elements(equipments,floors,rooms,spaces etc)

Comment: The Revit file is in BIM360 docs or forge bucket?

Comment: forge bucket sir

Comment: Please help on this to get all element or any solution to resolve the below error 
"Token does not have the privilege for this request." error code is AUTH-010

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have given the proper scopes, call this API using the internal token from your server.

Ref:

https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/?id=scopes
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/scopes/